# JavaFX ListView Timeline Scroll Animation is Jumpy (choppy)

Tags: listview, animation, javafx, scroll, timeline

I'm using a JavaFX ListView and Timeline to animate scrolling of a list. When the scroll animation is slow the text is jumpy (choppy). I have tried using an AnimationTimer to scroll the text. The text was also jumpy (choppy) during slow scrolling. The ListView control is necessary for the virtual viewport characteristics. Following is an example that recreates the problem on my Mac using Java Version 1.8.

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Jumpy extends Application {

    ListView listView;
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    double speed = 0.0000005;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        List list = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
            Text text = new Text("Random line of text to show how it is choppy during scroll animation");
            text.setStyle("-fx-font-size: " + 4 + "em");
            list.add(text);
        }
        ObservableList observableList = FXCollections.observableList(list);
        listView = new ListView((observableList));
        listView.setPrefWidth(600);

        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        root.getChildren().addAll(listView, buttons());

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }

    public void scroll() {
        ScrollBar scrollBar = getVerticalScrollBar();
        EventHandler scroll = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                scrollBar.setValue(scrollBar.getValue() + speed);
            }
        };

        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.setAutoReverse(false);
        KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(scrollBar.valueProperty(), 1);
        KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.017), scroll);
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
        timeline.play();
    }

    public ScrollBar getVerticalScrollBar() {
        ScrollBar scrollBar = null;
        for (Node node : listView.lookupAll(".scroll-bar")) {
            if (node instanceof ScrollBar) {
                scrollBar = (ScrollBar) node;
                if ((scrollBar.getOrientation().compareTo(Orientation.VERTICAL)) == 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return scrollBar;
    }

    public HBox buttons() {
        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        Button start = new Button("start");
        start.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                scroll();
            }
        });
        Button slower = new Button("slower");
        slower.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                ScrollBar scrollBar = getVerticalScrollBar();
                EventHandler scroll = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                        scrollBar.setValue(scrollBar.getValue() - 0.000001);
                    }
                };
                KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10.0D), scroll);
                timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
            }

        });
        Button faster = new Button("faster");
        faster.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                ScrollBar scrollBar = getVerticalScrollBar();
                EventHandler scroll = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                        scrollBar.setValue(scrollBar.getValue() + 0.000001);
                    }
                };
                KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10.0D), scroll);
                timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);

            }
        });
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(start, slower, faster);
        return hBox;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no point in using a virtualized control if you're just going to populate it with 2000 `Node` instances: you completely destroy almost all the benefits of using the virtualization in the first place.

Populate the control with data (e.g., in this case, `String`s) and either style the `ListView` or use a cell factory to control how the values are displayed.

The following performs much better for me:

```
ListView<String> listView;
Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
double speed = 0.0000005;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
        String text = "Random line of text to show how it is choppy during scroll animation";
        //  text.setStyle("-fx-font-size: " + 4 + "em");
        list.add(text);
    }
    ObservableList<String> observableList = FXCollections.observableList(list);
    listView = new ListView<String>((observableList));
    listView.setPrefWidth(600);

    listView.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 4em; ");

    AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
    root.getChildren().addAll(listView, buttons());

    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.show();
}
```

After this change, using an `AnimationTimer` seems slightly smoother still. Here's an example using this approach (and with all the redundant code removed):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Jumpy extends Application {

    ListView<String> listView;
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    double increment = 2e-5 ;
    double speed = 5*increment ;

    AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {

        private long lastUpdate = -1 ;
        private ScrollBar scrollbar ;

        @Override
        public void start() {
            scrollbar = getVerticalScrollBar();
            super.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            if (lastUpdate < 0) {
                lastUpdate = now ;
                return ;
            }

            long elapsedNanos = now - lastUpdate ;
            double delta = speed * elapsedNanos / 1_000_000_000 ;
            scrollbar.setValue(scrollbar.getValue() + delta);

            lastUpdate = now ;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
            String text = "Random line of text to show how it is choppy during scroll animation";
            list.add(text);
        }
        ObservableList<String> observableList = FXCollections.observableList(list);
        listView = new ListView<String>((observableList));
        listView.setPrefWidth(600);

        listView.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 4em; ");

        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        root.getChildren().addAll(listView, buttons());

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }

    private ScrollBar getVerticalScrollBar() {
        ScrollBar scrollBar = null;
        for (Node node : listView.lookupAll(".scroll-bar")) {
            if (node instanceof ScrollBar) {
                scrollBar = (ScrollBar) node;
                if (scrollBar.getOrientation() == Orientation.VERTICAL) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return scrollBar;
    }

    private HBox buttons() {
        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        Button start = new Button("start");
        start.setOnAction(event -> timer.start());
        Button slower = new Button("slower");
        slower.setOnAction(event -> speed -= increment);
        Button faster = new Button("faster");
        faster.setOnAction(event -> speed += increment);
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(start, slower, faster);
        return hBox;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: James_D thank you the detailed response. I am getting the same jumpy (choppy) behavior using your example. BTW... the 2000 elements in the ListView is contrived in my application this number can be much larger. What I found is using a plain List actually a ScrollPane with a large font created performance issues.

Comment: @Tim Well, it looks pretty smooth for me with either version of the code I posted. It definitely has performance issues with the code you have - it seems reasonable to assume that the difference is caused by creating so many `Node` instances.

Comment: Thank you again for your response. You are right it is much better but still a little jumpy. I created another example using the flowless VirtualizedScrollPane with the richtext StyleClassedTextArea and some ideas from your example (AnimatedTimer scrolling). These controls are lighter weight than the ListView and produce smooth animations when scrolling. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Tim Yes: flowless will also improve performance over the standard virtualized panes. The biggest difference should be limiting the number of UI nodes created, by avoiding using UI nodes as data elements though.